# vb.net ~ How to add folder names from a directory to a list box

Tags: vb.net, listbox, visual-studio-2013, directory

I'm trying to add folder names from within a directpory specified by the user to a list box. I have tried a few solutions, but can't seem to add any items. Most recently I tried:

```
For Each folder As String In System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("D:\")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(folder)
Next
```

The form was built using VB in VB Studio Express 2013. There were no errors when running the program.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, then please help!

Comment: Obviously that code was broken down into three lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a list of Directories you need to call [Directory.GetDirectories(path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not [Path.GetDirectoryName(path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that, in your case returns just null (passing the root directory of a drive)

```
For Each folder As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("D:\")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(folder)
Next
```

if you want to show only the folder name and not the full path, just use

```
For Each folder As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("D:\")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(folder))
Next
```

Yes, I know, it seems wrong to ask for GetFileName over a folder name, but passing a full path to GetFileName returns just the folder without the path.

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I modified slightly to just display the folder names and not the paths: "ListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(folder))". I have another question though as I've realised a problem with what I'm using. More than just add items to a listbox, I would like a box to replicate the folders in a directory. So if the user specifies a new directory, the new contents will be displayed. Also, is it not possible for a user to selct more than one item in a listbox. I'm hoping on running some code based on their selection, which may be multiple folders. Should I be using a combobx?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your comment

Comment: Probably it is better to ask a new question specifying these requirements with an example.

Comment: Thanks. I was posting that exact solution as you were ha! If you can shed some light on my next comments, I would be most appreciative. This is only my third day using VB so lots to learn ha!

Comment: OK, I will post a new question! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how to select folder name to preview picture

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each folder As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Program Files (x86)\KONAMI\Pro Evolution Soccer 2016\SFXPath\SweetFX")
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(folder))

    Next
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged


    If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "folder" Then PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\Program Files (x86)\KONAMI\Pro Evolution Soccer 2016\SFXPath\SweetFX\HD Natural by pimplo\preview.jpg"
End Sub
End Class
```